# TypeError when executing jupyter nbconvert

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm having trouble running `jupyter nbconvert`.

It always shows the following error trace (even with a notebook with a few vanilla cells)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 596, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 293, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 447, in convert_notebooks
    self.exporter = cls(config=self.config)
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 151, in __init__
    super(TemplateExporter, self).__init__(config=config, **kw)
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 101, in __init__
    self._init_preprocessors()
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 250, in _init_preprocessors
    self.register_preprocessor(preprocessor, enabled=True)
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 211, in register_preprocessor
    preprocessor_cls = import_item(preprocessor)
  File "/home/miguel/.virtualenvs/ipython/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
TypeError: Item in ``from list'' not a string
```

It might be related with the nbextensions which I recently installed, since some days ago the `jupyter nbconvert` command used to work perfectly.

Today, I've been having some trouble installing the nbextensions. I tried using conda, but finally the it worked when I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/#1-install-the-python-package).

Comment: Do you have a `~/.jupyter/jupyter_nbconvert_config.py` (or `.json`) file?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. It seems this is a bug in nbconvert, as documented [here](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/362). The solution is to edit your "jupyter_nbconvert_config.json" file. For me, this was located in my home directory by default: /home/me/.jupyter/jupyter_nbconvert_config.json

There, I changed the preprocessor strings, adding an "r" in front of them:

```
{
  "Exporter": {
    "template_path": [
      ".", 
      "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/templates"
    ], 
    "preprocessors": [
      r"jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.CodeFoldingPreprocessor", 
      r"jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.PyMarkdownPreprocessor"
    ]
  }, 
  "NbConvertApp": {
    "postprocessor_class":     "jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.EmbedPostProcessor"
  }, 
  "version": 1
}
```

Comment: Adding r to strings in the JSON config causes a JSONDecodedError. This seemed to work (pending an updated release of ipython_genutils): https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/362#issuecomment-246169144

Comment: worked for me. I had to change TWO identical JSON files: one in `~/.jupyter/`, and another one in `~/anaconda/etc/jupyter`. For some strange reason, changing only one file didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution [here](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/34826/jupyter-notebook-extensions-in-sage-73/).
Basically, you need to remove or rename your jupyter_nbconvert_config file.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed recently, see the details [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython_genutils/commit/3d47e88).  Run a full update for ipython or, to fix manually:

**change line 31** in your ipython_genutils/importstring.py from

```
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
```

to

```
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[str(obj)])
```